# Unable to focus on a field if a field is selected already

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I am making a login page using jQuery. The person has to scan their ID barcode and when they do it will show the 'password' field, where they will enter their password. my problem is when the barcode scanner reads the barcode it uses the tab key and that field loses focus, and then puts focus on another field (more specifically my search box on firefox) and i am then unable to put focus back onto the next (password) field.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <div class="loginbox">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div class="logonform">
            <form method="post" id="loginform">
                <span id="studentid">ID Number: <input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentidb"></span>
                <span id="password" style="display: none">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordb"></span>
            </form>
                    </div>
    </div>
    <script><!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#studentidb").focus().select();
    });
    $("#studentidb").blur(function(){
        $("#studentid").hide();
        $("#password").show();
        $("#password").focus();
    });
    $("#passwordb").blur(function(){
        $("#loginform").submit();
    });
    --></script>
```

And yes, I do have jQuery included at the top of the page.

Comment: Is this for mobile devices? If so then you should tag the question appropriately.

Comment: No, it is not. what would drive you to think that it is...

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the focus on `$("#password")` which is the span.

try setting the the focus on the input which is `$("#passwordb")`.

Comment: That was messed up when i was debugging, in my regular version i do have $("#passwordb") and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling the show password then focusing it and then hiding the id field later

```
 $("#studentidb").blur(function(){
    $("#password").show();
    $("#password").focus();
    $("#studentid").hide();

});
```